# Integration of Superset with Keycloak OAUTH2

Tags: python, python-3.x, keycloak, apache-superset

I am trying to use keycloak with apache superset but, i use the authentication OAuth2 , i have error with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'create_client_secret_json'
any idea ?

```
import logging
import os
####ADDED#######
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID
from cachelib.file import FileSystemCache
from create_client_secret_json import create_client_secret_json
from security import OIDCSecurityManager
```

Comment: where is ```create_client_secret_json``` from?

Comment: create_client_secret_json is as a plugin but don't work , how can i resolve this issue ?